# Calculate then append

Tags: jquery, math, append

I need the two inputs to be be calculated into a percent using jQuery, then the result appended to the result div.

```
<input type="text" value="27" class="numerator" />
<input type="text" value="30" class="denominator" />

<div class="result"></div>
```

Formula: (numerator * denominator) / 100

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll need to post what you've tried. This isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
var numerator = $('.numerator').val(),
    denominator = $('.denominator').val();

var percent = parseFloat((numerator/denominator) * 100).toFixed(2);

$('.result').html(function() {
    return percent + '%'
});
```

Add some additional checks to check for `division by 0` and a change event if you want it to be dynamic.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/geB4x/)**

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd, especially since your formula doesn't make since. Are you sure you don't want `numerator/denominator*100`? Anyway - this should work for what it seems you want: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BKYKe/)

```
$('.result').text($('.numerator')[0].value * $('.denominator')[0].value / 100);
```

Since you are using classes, I'm assuming possibly you have multiple? And since you are doing it in an `input`, perhaps you want it to update if changed? If so, you could try something like this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BKYKe/1/)

```
function update($ele) {
    var n = Number($ele.find('.numerator')[0].value);
    var d = Number($ele.find('.denominator')[0].value);
    $ele.find('.result').text(n * d / 100);
}
$('.group').each( function() {
    update($(this));
});
$('.group input').on('keyup', function() {
    update($(this).closest('.group'));
});
```

And here is one with a real percentage formula... [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BKYKe/3/)